# Powershell - SaveFileDialog creates txt file temporarily

Tags: powershell, user-interface, openfiledialog, txt, savefiledialog

I want to create a GUI in Powershell where the user selects a path to save an empty txt file. For this I use SaveFileDialog. When I run the code below, the file is created temporarily. It is not saved permanently. What do I need to change?

```
Function fileSave
{
$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.CheckPathExists = $true
$OpenFileDialog.CreatePrompt = true;
$OpenFileDialog.OverwritePrompt = true;
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$Directory = $OpenFileDialog.FileName = 'NewFile'
$OpenFileDialog.Title = 'Choose directory to save the output file'
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"

# Show save file dialog box
if($OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok'){
    $NewFile = New-Item -Path "$Directory" -ItemType File -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to reference the [`FileName` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-filedialog-filename) inside your `if` condition, it will be the absolute path of the file *to be created*. Aside from that, you're using `true` instead of `$true`.

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function fileSave {
    $saveFileDialog = [System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog]@{
        CheckPathExists  = $true
        CreatePrompt     = $true
        OverwritePrompt  = $true
        InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
        FileName         = 'NewFile'
        Title            = 'Choose directory to save the output file'
        Filter           = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"
    }

    # Show save file dialog box
    if($saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'Ok') {
        New-Item -Path $saveFileDialog.FileName -ItemType File -Force
    }
}

fileSave
```